# Input / sign into span element wait for popup and continue text input

Tags: jira, playwright, confluence

I can not resolve script implementation with input / sing into main context of confluence page, wait for popup with available applications and continue text input. I have next current implementation

`await page.locator('[aria-label="Main content area"] p').type('/')`

because only type can apply text for not text area element.

Then I wait for popup action menu (it works ok).

`await page.waitForSelector('[role="listbox"]')`

But when after it I try to specify name of application, playwright replaces / sign and menu goes away.

`await page.locator('[aria-label="Main content area"] p').type(nameOfApplication)`

How such approach can be implemented? Because for a call of actions menu / sign should be specified in the beginning, then wait for action menu and continue input application name. And as final click on interested application (click also is implemented) which appeared.
[image]

Comment: Why can't you write both steps together?
await page.locator('[aria-label="Main content area"] p').type('/' + nameOfApplication);

Comment: Because then  I actions menu will appear